# How to handle socket listener infinite loop in GUI program?

Tags: c#, listener, infinite-loop, asyncsocket

I'm creating a simple asynchronous socket listener that acts as a gateway to devices. This listener will listen to an arbitrary port and provides an API for other software to access devices over the network.

To create an asynchronous socket listener, [based on this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx), I have to create an infinite loop, like this:

```
while (true) {
    // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
    allDone.Reset();

    // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
    listener.BeginAccept( 
        new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
        listener
    );

    // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
    allDone.WaitOne();
}
```

The console program prototype runs well. However, I intend to create a GUI version of the asynchronous socket listener. I know that if I do the infinite loop in the GUI, the GUI will hang. How do I give a graphical user interface to the listener? I'm hoping for a simple solution that doesn't involve threads.

Comment: You're using threads -- see the documentation for [AsyncCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback.aspx).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Thanks for the correction :) - I didn't know that. Using asynchronous socket listener API in C# is much more simple than spawning and managing threads yourself

Answer (score 1):

Either you can put the loop in a separate thread.

Or use the "asynch" part of the above code: When socket is created call `BeginAccept`, and in the callback do it again when done with processing. This way you don't need signals or loops at all.

Comment: Can you point me to the right documentation for learning threads? It seems that there is no other way. Also, when I spawn a thread for the infinite loop, will the `BeginAccept` method spawn new threads?